# Why does this image not center with margin auto?

Tags: css, margin

The logo image at the top of this page `http://54.251.57.136/` should center with:

```
.logo-img {
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: block;
}
```

... but it doesn't and I can't figure out why.  Any help would be great.

Comment: Firebug is fantastic to debug these things!

Comment: Thanks @nico I use Chrome's dev tools, which is very similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take off the float: left from logo-img and add text-align: center

Comment: How can I take off the float without modifying the parent stylesheet its inherited from?

Comment: Add float: none; and text-align: center;

Answer (score 2):

Your div has a  class .logo-img  which is set to float:left.  (and it would need a fixed width for the centering to work)

Comment: the OP also needs to add a width to that div for centering with margins to work..

Comment: adding `float:none` doesn't change anything..?

Comment: Don't add float:none, just remove float:left; and give the div the same width the actual image has.

Comment: Can I remove float:left when I don't have access to the parent stylesheet that contains it?

Answer (score 0):

You are floating the image wrapper, if you adjust your css you can center it:

**ADD THIS TO YOUR <sup>.logo-img</sup>**

```
text-align: center;
```

**REMOVE THIS FROM YOUR <sup>.logo-img</sup>**

```
float:left;
```

#### What do you need to know:

- Floated elements get off the normal document flow, so `margin:0
  auto;` does not apply. You need to remove it.
- `margin:0 auto;` on the `.logo-img` tag is not enough, you need to add
  `text-align:center;` to allow the image to get centered.

Answer (score -1):

1. Your logo-img class has a float: left
2. You must declare width on the div if you want it to center automatically with margin: auto. In this case width: 572px